# What does `git reset --mixed` do in terms of index if there's no current branch

Tags: git

As I understand when I run `git reset` without any parameters and paths it defaults to `--mixed` which git manual describes as:

> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are
>   preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been
>   updated.

I'm wondering what does it reset it to? I assume that it reads some tree into index file using `git read-tree`, but where does it find that tree? Some other options explain that the tree is found in the `HEAD` file which points to a commit or branch and hence a tree hash can be resolved.

However, I've used `git read-tree aa23` to put the tree into index and currently my `HEAD` file contains the following:

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

But there's no branch created yet. 
The tree contains two files:

```
$ git ls-files -s
100644 a1deaae8f9ac984a5bfd0e8eecfbafaf4a90a3d0 0       f1.txt
100644 9b96e21cb748285ebec53daec4afb2bdcb9a360a 0       f2.txt
```

And when I run the `git reset` I get no errors, `git status` reports no changes and `git ls-files -s` reports no files. So what did the index was reset to?

Comment: It resets the index to the tree of the commit you asked it to reset to. If you don't specify a commit, it resets to HEAD.

Comment: right, but that's the question, I didn't specify any commit. And `HEAD` contains reference to the non-existing branch

Comment: If you've only initialized an empty repository, reset will empty the index.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, got, thanks. So to generalize, if GIT can't resolve a tree by following `HEAD` it simply empties the index, correct?

Comment: No, it emptied the index because you don't have any commits in the repository to reset to (just after `git init`). If you have commits in the repository, but HEAD is corrupted (points to a branch that doesn't exist) then I don't know what happens, I assume this behavior is undefined.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, just tried to create a commit manually with `echo 'initial commit' | git commit-tree e05d9da`. Then checked out the tree with `read-tree` and `checkout-index`. Then ran `git reset` and got no error although one commit exists. Have empty index file. So probably git resets to the empty index if it can't resolve the tree by `HEAD`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running `git reset` on an unborn branch, Git explicitly uses the [semi-secret empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) as [the target of the reset](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b3622a4ee94e4916cd05e6d96e41eeb36b941182/builtin/reset.c#L316):

```
unborn = !strcmp(rev, "HEAD") && get_sha1("HEAD", oid.hash);
if (unborn) {
        /* reset on unborn branch: treat as reset to empty tree */
        hashcpy(oid.hash, EMPTY_TREE_SHA1_BIN);
} else if (!pathspec.nr) {
```

With the top level tree being empty, the correct (at least notionally) result for resetting the index entry for any path *P* is to remove *P* from the index.

Comment: great, thanks again! I'm writing an article on git internals, I'll drop it here tomorrow, if you have time maybe you'll quickly skim it for technical inconsistencies?